# Cloning the diff files from 2 branches

Tags: git, diff, git-clone, git-diff

I am wondering if it is possible to only clone the files that are different from two different branches (say branch 2 has an additional of 30 files compared to branch 1 and you only wish to clone those files using git)

Comment: Nope... you can't selectively clone some files. It sounds like you should consider a sparse checkout (and perhaps a shallow clone?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not work with *files*, at this level.  Git works with *commits*.  You *clone* a repository by copying commits, not files.

It's true that commits *contain* files, but:

- every commit contains a *full snapshot of every* file (plus metadata)
- though the files are in a special Git-ized format where they're *de-duplicated* within and across commits

Git is smart enough that when you clone a repository and pick up new commits, you *already only get the new files*.  This smartness has certain limitations: in particular, if you make a *shallow* or *partial* clone, it becomes less effective.

In other words, just make a regular clone and you'll likely get exactly what you want.  If you fiddle around too much with shallow and/or the fancy new partial clone, you'll actually make things *worse*.  But if regular clones *are* too slow, try out the shallow and/or partial clone features to see if they help.

(If you're making a lot of clones, consider using `--reference`.  Note that `--reference` tries hard to *share* the object databases across the various clones by default, which means that the clone(s) you use *as* the reference clones *must be especially stable*.  If they're not so stable, add `--dissociate` as well, so that the new clone works by copying instead of sharing.)